# docfx project with git under tfs

Tags: git, tfs, docfx

I'm trying to create docfx project. Sources are hosted on TFS server in GIT repository.

Everything is ok except absence of **Improve this Doc** link.

Is there way to make this link appear and work for such configuration?

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you use DocFx Build Tasks[https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chrismason.vsts-docfxtasks] to generate documentation site? You could follow this blog [https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/04/14/documentation-in-a-devops-world/] to use DocFx Build Tasks. If misunderstand anything, please share your steps here.

Comment: Version 15.117.26714.0

Comment: Do you use DocFx Build Tasks to generate documentation site?

Comment: No. I created `git` repo on `TFS`. Then clone it, then run _docfx init_ in local copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this part to `docfx.json`

```
"globalMetadata": {
  "_gitUrlPattern": "vso"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I could reproduce your scenario. There is no Improve this Doc link when you the repo clone from TFS 2017, but the link does show up when you clone repo from VSTS. It seems Improve this Doc link doesn't support on-premises TFS, I'd like to suggest you open an issue on the site below to get help from Docfx side:

https://github.com/dotnet/docfx/issues

Comment: Kindly post back the solution if the issue is solved.